# Добавить изображение в Button

Tags: java, javafx

Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть кнопка Button. В папке resources/img/ есть иконка add_icon.png. Как эту иконку поставить вместо текста на кнопке?

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте ей картинку через стили
`-fx-graphic: url('/resources/img/add_icon.png')`
или кодом
`button.setGraphic(new ImageView(someImage));`

Дополнительно стоит удалить отображение текста с кнопки, что бы этот блок не мешал выравниваниям/размерам через стили `-fx-content-display: graphic-only` или кодом`button.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);`